# How to Add Primeng Megamenu in newly added Component in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I created a angular 13 and PrimeNG 13. I generated a component named header. I am trying to add Mega menu . How do i add it on header component. I am trying to learn a new technology please help regarding this

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MegaMenuModule } from 'primeng/megamenu';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    MegaMenuModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

headercomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MegaMenuItem } from 'primeng/api';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  items: MegaMenuItem[] | undefined;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = [
      {
          label: 'Videos', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-video',
          items: [
              [
                  {
                      label: 'Video 1',
                      items: [{label: 'Video 1.1'}, {label: 'Video 1.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'Video 2',
                      items: [{label: 'Video 2.1'}, {label: 'Video 2.2'}]
                  }
              ],
              [
                  {
                      label: 'Video 3',
                      items: [{label: 'Video 3.1'}, {label: 'Video 3.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'Video 4',
                      items: [{label: 'Video 4.1'}, {label: 'Video 4.2'}]
                  }
              ]
          ]
      },
      {
          label: 'Users', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-users',
          items: [
              [
                  {
                      label: 'User 1',
                      items: [{label: 'User 1.1'}, {label: 'User 1.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'User 2',
                      items: [{label: 'User 2.1'}, {label: 'User 2.2'}]
                  },
              ],
              [
                  {
                      label: 'User 3',
                      items: [{label: 'User 3.1'}, {label: 'User 3.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'User 4',
                      items: [{label: 'User 4.1'}, {label: 'User 4.2'}]
                  }
              ],
              [
                  {
                      label: 'User 5',
                      items: [{label: 'User 5.1'}, {label: 'User 5.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'User 6',
                      items: [{label: 'User 6.1'}, {label: 'User 6.2'}]
                  }
              ]
          ]
      },
      {
          label: 'Events', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar',
          items: [
              [
                  {
                      label: 'Event 1',
                      items: [{label: 'Event 1.1'}, {label: 'Event 1.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'Event 2',
                      items: [{label: 'Event 2.1'}, {label: 'Event 2.2'}]
                  }
              ],
              [
                  {
                      label: 'Event 3',
                      items: [{label: 'Event 3.1'}, {label: 'Event 3.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'Event 4',
                      items: [{label: 'Event 4.1'}, {label: 'Event 4.2'}]
                  }
              ]
          ]
      },
      {
          label: 'Settings', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-cog',
          items: [
              [
                  {
                      label: 'Setting 1',
                      items: [{label: 'Setting 1.1'}, {label: 'Setting 1.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'Setting 2',
                      items: [{label: 'Setting 2.1'}, {label: 'Setting 2.2'}]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'Setting 3',
                      items: [{label: 'Setting 3.1'}, {label: 'Setting 3.2'}]
                  }
              ],
              [
                  {
                      label: 'Technology 4',
                      items: [{label: 'Setting 4.1'}, {label: 'Setting 4.2'}]
                  }
              ]
          ]
      }
  ]
  }

}
```

header.component.html

```
<header class="header">
    <p-megaMenu [model]="items"></p-megaMenu>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason items: MegaMenuItem[] = []; from items: MegaMenuItem[] | any;